# How can I create advanced recurring event rules in Google Calendar?

Tags: icalendar, google-calendar-recurring-events

I've recently taken over some accounting responsibilities at my workplace. Office payroll is due on the 10th and 25th of each month, but in order for the money to arrive on time, it must be processed at the very latest by 5:00 PM two business days prior to the last business day on or before these payroll due dates. How can I set something like this up in Google Calendar?

I've been reading up on iCal import tweaks (create an iCal file and import it instead of making the event in gCal, to have more flexibility) but can't find a way to subtract a number of days (or business days at that).

```
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYSETPOS=-2
SUMMARY:Pay Office Staff
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20190815
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:Send office payroll.
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I have no idea how to make it work except to do the date math in a Google Apps Script and have it create the events each month. I'm hoping someone can direct me to where I can find more information about how to achieve my desired result. I expect when it's done (if even possible) that I'll have a recurring event that takes place 2 business days prior to the last business day on or before the the 10th and another for the 25th.

Comment: Perhaps using the REST API? https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents

Comment: @IronMan It looks like I would still have to use RRULE format for recurrence, which AFAIK doesn't allow for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: far from being garanteed to be supported but by rfc5545 something like this should give the occurences you are looking for: RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=13,14,15,23,24,25;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=-4,-1